# Apache Test Screen showing after Drupal Install

Tags: server, apache2, drupal

**Problem**

I'm running Ubuntu server 13.04. I installed drupal in the path below, running localhost/drupal/install.php

```
/var/www/drupal
```

Drupal installed correctly but the address `localhost/drupal` redirects me to the apache test page rather than the drupal site as it normally does.

What have I done wrong?

**Relevant Log**

I've tried to guess the relevant log as there is a lot of other stuff in there.

```
[Thu Oct 10 11:52:14 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.73] File does not exist: /var/www/drupal/drupal
[Thu Oct 10 11:52:16 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.73] File does not exist: /var/www/drupal/drupal
```

Comment: What do the logs say? (in `/var/log/apache`, especially the `error.log`)

Comment: @Calimo. So I managed to fix it// A. by just pasting it in the root and then by deleting the apache index and putting it back into a folder. I got a weird error in the log which I thought might've been it.

Comment: Then you can answer your own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `index.html` from /var/www with

`sudo rm /var/www/index.html`

Usually, by default, installing the LAMP stack will also install a default `index.html` at `/var/www` which may confuse the script/site being installed on that folder. Deleting that default HTML file will ensure that apache will load the file `index.php` instead.

Comment: Why he should remove this file?

Comment: That does work. Any idea why?

Comment: @Braiam Usually, by default, when the LAMP stack is installed, it comes with the default index.html on /var/www which confuses any script/site that you install on /var/www so deleting the default index.html probably will do the trick. if this works for you then you may accept the answer.

Comment: Can you add that explanation to the answer itself?